# C++ multi-threading Error: Single producer Multiple consumer

Tags: c++, multithreading, producer-consumer, condition-variable

I am trying to achieve Single producer Multiple consumer , however below code is not able to compile.
Can someone help with this error ? Also would it work to wake all threads from this pool & a random thread would be able to acquire the lock?

- TIA

> ```
> `
> threadPool/main.cpp:4:
> /Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/thread:364:17:
> ```
>
> error: no matching constructor for initialization of '_Gp' (aka
> 'tuple<unique_ptrstd::__1::__thread_struct, void (TestClass::*)(),
> TestClass>')
> new _Gp(std::move(__tsp),
> ^   ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
>
> ```
> ls/usr/bin/../include/c++/v1/type_traits:2422:12: error: call to implicitly-deleted copy constructor of 'typename
> ```
>
> decay::type' (aka 'TestClass')
> return _VSTD::forward<_Tp>(__t);
>
> ```
> ----------------------------------------------
> ```

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>

using namespace std;


class TestClass{

public:
    void producer(int i) {
        unique_lock<mutex> lockGuard(mtx);
        Q.push(i);
        lockGuard.unlock();
        cond.notify_all();
    }


    void consumer() {
        unique_lock<mutex> lockGuard(mtx);
        cond.wait(lockGuard, [this]() {
            return !Q.empty();
        });
        cout<<this_thread::get_id();
        cout<<Q.front()<<endl;
        Q.pop();
        lockGuard.unlock();
    };

private:
    mutex mtx;
    condition_variable cond;
    queue<int> Q;

};

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    int MAX_THREADS = std::thread::hardware_concurrency()-1;
    vector<thread> ThreadVector;

    TestClass testObj;
    for(int i=0; i<MAX_THREADS; i++){
        ThreadVector.emplace_back(&TestClass::consumer, std::move(testObj));
        cout<<"Pool threadID:" <<ThreadVector[i].get_id()<<endl;
    }


    TestClass testObj2;
    for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
        testObj.producer(i);
    }


    for(auto &&t : ThreadVector) {
        t.join();
    }

    return 0;
}


`

Another version to call threads
int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> vecOfThreads;
    std::function<void(TestClass&)> func = [&](TestClass &obj) {
        while(1) {
            obj.consumer();
        }
    };

    unsigned MAX_THREADS = std::thread::hardware_concurrency()-1;
    TestClass obj;
    for(int i=0; i<MAX_THREADS; i++) {
        std::thread th1(func, std::ref(obj));
        vecOfThreads.emplace_back(std::move(th1));
    }

   TestClass prod;
   for(int i=0; i<10; i++) {
       prod.producer(i);
   }
    for (std::thread & th : vecOfThreads)
    {
        if (th.joinable())
            th.join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `mutex` cannot be moved and thus `TestClass` cannot be moved (not to mention that you do `std::move` in a loop on the same object which is an unspecified behaviour). If you want to share `TestClass` between threads then allocate it on the heap, e.g. use `std::shared_ptr` (or something) instead, and pass that pointer around. You could pass it as `&testObj` as well but for that you need to take special care about liveness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- `std::move(testObj)` should be `&testObj` (a pointer to the object to call `consumer` on) - or `std::ref(testobj)` (which becomes a `reference_wrapper` (holding a pointer to the object too).
- You should call `produce` at least as many times as you have threads, or else the program won't finish.
- You don't need to `unlock` manually. The guards unlock automatically when they go out of scope.

Example:

```
class TestClass {
public:
    void producer(int i) {
        lock_guard<mutex> lockGuard(mtx); // here a lock_guard is enough
        Q.push(i);
        // no manual unlocking
        cond.notify_all(); 
    }

    void consumer() {
        unique_lock<mutex> lockGuard(mtx);
        cond.wait(lockGuard, [this] { return !Q.empty(); });
        cout << this_thread::get_id();
        cout << Q.front() << endl;
        Q.pop();
    };

private:
    mutex mtx;
    condition_variable cond;
    queue<int> Q;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    unsigned MAX_THREADS = std::thread::hardware_concurrency() - 1;
    vector<thread> ThreadVector;
    ThreadVector.reserve(MAX_THREADS); // since you know how many, reserve

    TestClass testObj;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
        // here, &testobj
        ThreadVector.emplace_back(&TestClass::consumer, &testObj);

        cout << "Pool threadID:" << ThreadVector[i].get_id() << endl;
    }

    // produce MAX_THREADS of things to put in the queue:
    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
        testObj.producer(i);
    }

    for(auto&& t : ThreadVector) {
        t.join();
    }
}
```

---

Regarding your questions in the comment section: If you'd like to keep the `consumer` threads running until you tell them to quit, you could add another variable (called `run` here) that the `consumer` threads monitor.

Example:

```
#include <condition_variable>
#include <iostream>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class TestClass {
public:
    void producer(int i) {
        lock_guard<mutex> lockGuard(mtx);
        Q.push(i);
        to_pool.notify_one();
    }

    void consumer() {
        while(true) {
            unique_lock<mutex> lockGuard(mtx);
            to_pool.wait(lockGuard, [this] { return !run || !Q.empty(); });

            if(!run) break; // time to quit

            cout << this_thread::get_id() << ' ' << Q.front() << endl;
            Q.pop();

            // Tell producer that we picked one from the queue.
            // if it's only interesting to notify when the queue is empty,
            // add: if(Q.empty())
            to_producer.notify_one();
        }
    };

    void stop() {
        lock_guard<mutex> lockGuard(mtx);
        run = false;            // tell all pool threads to quit
        to_pool.notify_all();
    }

    void wait_for_all_work_to_be_done() {
        std::unique_lock<mutex> lg(mtx);
        to_producer.wait(lg, [this] { return Q.empty(); });
    }

private:
    bool run = true;
    mutex mtx;
    condition_variable to_pool;
    condition_variable to_producer;
    queue<int> Q;
};

int main() {
    std::cout << "Hello, World!" << std::endl;
    unsigned MAX_THREADS = std::thread::hardware_concurrency() - 1;
    vector<thread> ThreadVector;
    ThreadVector.reserve(MAX_THREADS);

    TestClass testObj;
    for(unsigned i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++) {
        ThreadVector.emplace_back(&TestClass::consumer, &testObj);

        cout << "Pool threadID:" << ThreadVector[i].get_id() << endl;
    }

    for(int i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS / 2; i++) {
        testObj.producer(i);
    }

    testObj.wait_for_all_work_to_be_done();

    // stop pool threads
    testObj.stop();

    for(auto&& t : ThreadVector) t.join();
}
```

Comment: Do you really need to add both of these lines to the consumer?
    ```unique_lock<mutex> lockGuard(mtx);
        cond.wait(lockGuard, [this]() { return !Q.empty(); });```
Does it not lock producer from adding to Q?

Comment: @Attis Yes -  which line would you suggest can be removed?

Comment: I thought you can omit the first line when waiting for the notification for the condition variable.

Comment: You mean, doing it without locking the `mutex`? In that case, the access to `Q` wouldn't be guarded.

Comment: Thanks @TedLyngmo !! That worked.
However, in this case I would need to use cond.notify_all() to wake up all threads. Right?  And cond.notify_one() wouldn't work!!!

Comment: @user8707488 Yes, `notify_one()` should work fine here I'd say.

Comment: @TedLyngmo How can I re-use the consumer threads ? Looks like it gets spawned only these many times & died. How can I put them back in thread pool? If I add while(1) loop in consumer() , it is giving new thread ID everytime

Comment: @user8707488 You only have one producer thread currently. It's the thread running in `main`. if you want a pool, your `consumer` threads would have to loop internally until some condition is set which tells them to quit.

Comment: @user8707488 I added an example where the consumer/pool threads are kept running until you tell them to stop.

Comment: Thanks @TedLyngmo for genuine answers!! I promise last follow up question, trying to use function object in int main() but threads are not waking up

`int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> vecOfThreads;
    std::function<void(TestClass&)> func = [&](TestClass &obj) {
        while(1) {
            obj.consumer();
        }
    };

    unsigned MAX_THREADS = std::thread::hardware_concurrency()-1;
    TestClass obj;
    for(int i=0; i<MAX_THREADS; i++) {
        std::thread th1(func, std::ref(obj));
        vecOfThreads.emplace_back(std::move(th1));
    }
// Rest code is same
}`

Comment: @TedLyngmo Updated the `int main()` in the main question itself, many thanks!! Could you pl help with this query about using function objects?

Comment: @user8707488 The queston now changed too much. Instead of editing the question, I suggest doing a rollback of the last edit and open a new separate question for that new code.

Comment: let me do that and ping here the link of new question. @TedLyngmo

Comment: @user8707488 Just a note: I _think_ I know the problem. You have two separate `TestClass` objects. Your producer puts data in one queue and the consumers read from a different queue.

Comment: That resolved!! Need to be more mindful while coding, thanks again @TedLyngmo!

Comment: @TedLyngmo New question for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67381553/function-objects-multithreading-pool-giving-same-thread-id