# Function Objects & multithreading Pool giving same thread ID

Tags: c++, multithreading

For below program, thread Pool always picks the same thread ID 0x7000095f9000! Why so?
Should every push condi.notify_one() wake up all threads same time? What could be the reason same thread ID get picked?

Computer supports 3 threads.
Any other info on using function objects would be helpful!!

O/P

```
Checking if not empty
Not Empty
0x700009576000 0
Checking if not empty
Checking if not empty
Checking if not empty
Not Empty
0x7000095f9000 1
Checking if not empty
Not Empty
0x7000095f9000 2
Checking if not empty
Not Empty
0x7000095f9000 3
Checking if not empty
Not Empty
0x7000095f9000 4
Checking if not empty
Not Empty
0x7000095f9000 5
Checking if not empty
```

Code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <queue>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>
#include <chrono>

using namespace std;

class TestClass{

public:
    void producer(int i) {
        unique_lock<mutex> lockGuard(mtx);
        Q.push(i);
        cond.notify_all();
    }


    void consumer() {
            {
                unique_lock<mutex> lockGuard(mtx);
                cout << "Checking if not empty" << endl;
                cond.wait(lockGuard, [this]() {
                    return !Q.empty();
                });
                cout << "Not Empty" << endl;
                cout << this_thread::get_id()<<" "<<Q.front()<<endl;
                Q.pop();
            }
    };

    void consumerMain() {
        while(1) {
            consumer();
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(chrono::seconds(1));
        }
    }

private:
    mutex mtx;
    condition_variable cond;
    queue<int> Q;

};


int main()
{
    std::vector<std::thread> vecOfThreads;
    std::function<void(TestClass&)> func = [&](TestClass &obj) {
        while(1) {
            obj.consumer();
        }
    };

    unsigned MAX_THREADS = std::thread::hardware_concurrency()-1;
    TestClass obj;
    for(int i=0; i<MAX_THREADS; i++) {
        std::thread th1(func, std::ref(obj));
        vecOfThreads.emplace_back(std::move(th1));
    }

   for(int i=0; i<4*MAX_THREADS/2; i++) {
       obj.producer(i);
   }
    for (std::thread & th : vecOfThreads)
    {
        if (th.joinable())
            th.join();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Any other info on using function objects would be helpful!! Thanks in advance!!
Any other pointers?

Comment: Maybe make the thread doing "more" or "real" work. You cannot control how the OS schedules your threads and therefore one thread maybe consumes all the work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The very short unlocking of the `mutex` that happens in the consumer threads will in your case most probably let the running thread acquire the lock again, and again and again.

If you instead simulate some work being done after the workload has been picked from the queue by calling `consumerMain` (which sleeps a little) instead of `consumer`, you would likely see different threads picking up the workload.

```
    while(1) {
        obj.consumerMain();
    }
```

Comment: In single-producer multiple consumer problem, should producer & consumer hold same mutex?
Would it make more sense to have separate mutex for producer (mtx_producer) & separate common mutex for 
consumer threads? (mtx_common_consumer) for high performance.

Comment: @user8707488 What matters is that all access to a resource that is shared among threads is protected from simultaneous read/write operations. If the producer wants to make changes to the resource (like a queue) and the consumers also want to access the resource, they should all be using the same mutex.

Comment: Could you also shed some light on this query Ted? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67407668/threads-with-an-earliest-time-to-arrive-for-highest-priority-to-pick-up-the-task