# Threads with an earliest time to arrive for highest priority to pick up the task

Tags: c++, multithreading, condition-variable

Considering I have a thread pool performing the same work foo();
How can I select a thread effectively from thread pool based on their arrival time ? and notify that thread with earliest arrival time using condition variable? Is it possible?

Comment: Hmm, the thread with the "_earliest arrival time_" is the thread that gets the mutex lock when there is some work in the queue, but I may be misundersanding something.

Comment: So, you want the first thread that waited on the condition variable to be the one that's released when the condition variable is signaled? There's no direct way to do that. Why does it matter?

Comment: Basically producer has to signal the consumer thread pool . Thread pool comes with random(range) delay post signal. So that is how I am trying to suffice this condition of in range delay post signal by producer.
I can't just add sleep outside lock acquire, as cond.wait() is getting notified directly!
I hope I was able to convey the question. @TedLyngmo @ Pete

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand it yet. You'd normally want the threads in the pool to pick up a job, do the work and then go back into waiting for new jobs to arrive. If there's already a job in the queue, it'll pick that, if not, it'll wait. If you have multiple threads waiting when you put a job in the queue, a "random" thread will get notified, wake up and pick the job.

Comment: Oh, is that what you mean? You want the thread that started waiting for a job first to get the job? If so, why? That would create unnecessary overhead and slow the job dispatching down.

Comment: Requirement I am trying to address is anti-multithreading! :)
Basically after receiving the cond.notify_all(), all threads have to add delay (sleep) and then try accessing the mutex-lock (cond.wait() ) & win the lock for previous notification. { Whoever  thread wins the lock after random shortest delay post notify, will get lock and perform the job }

Comment: It is like adding another dynamic wait on `cond.wait()`  and then recheck and honor the prior `cond.wait()`  wakeup ! @TedLyngmo

Comment: Ok, I don't see a reason for this complex setup, but it sounds possible. Give it a try by adding the necessary extra stuff and post the code (if you don't get it working) and someone will probably be able to help out - or suggest a different approach to whatever this is supposed to be :-)

Answer (score -1):

I think this is a rough solution in pseudo C.
Workers call Idle to announce they have nothing to do.  Idle() returns when there is work for them.
SchedWork either dispatches a waiting Worker, or remembers how many can be dispatched in the future.  Workers will be dispatched in a FIFO protocol.

```
typedef struct Worker Worker;

struct Worker {
    CV    wakeme;
    Worker *next, *prev;
};

lock_t  ListLock;
Workers *avail;
unsigned NReady;

void Idle(Worker *me) {
    Lock(&ListLock);
    if (NReady == 0) {
        if (me->next = avail) {
            me->prev = avail->prev;
            avail->prev = me;
            me->prev->next = me;
        } else {
            avail = me->prev = me->next = me;
        }
        CondWait(&me->wakeme, &ListLock);
    } else {
        NReady--;
    }
    UnLock(&ListLock);
}

void SchedWork(void) {
    Worker *up;

    Lock(&ListLock);
    if (up = avail) {
        if (up != up->next) {
            up->next->prev = up->prev;
            up->prev->next = up->next;
            avail = up->next;
        } else {
            avail = 0;
        }
        CondSignal(&up->wakeme);
    } else {
        NReady++;
    }
    UnLock(&ListLock);
}
```

Comment: I guess @Dharman is anti-hope; but I did want to clearly indicate that this does not constitute a solution to your homework assignment, or help unwind the deplorable mess that C++ is; but rather indicates how trivial a thread dispatch based upon FIFO could be.  And C++ stuff could use it, if you are forced into that arena.

Comment: Without comments in the code it may be hard to understand what it does. You are also not motivating _why_ OP should create his/her own FIFO instead of using a standard `std::queue` in the first place. The FIFO implementation takes up most of the post, obscuring whatever logic you mean to convey by showing the pseudo code. Nothing in OP:s post indicates he/she needs help to "_unwind the deplorable mess that C++ is_" or that OP is forced into the C++ arena against his/her will, so it's a mystery why you deliberately avoid using _all_ things in the standard library by using raw pointers etc.

Comment: It is C, pseudo C actually, as the response says.  The lack of comments is a forcing function to read and understand the code.

Comment: .... and why is it (pseudo) C? It's a C++ question and you could have used a standard `std::queue` and the standard abstractions for the synchronization primitives in your pseudo code. It would have shortened your example down to a few lines of code where OP could focus on the important stuff in your idea. You're reinventing the wheel for no good reason. Not helpful.

Comment: I don't know c++, and it was also a multi threading and condition variable question.   I don't imagine it will be difficult someone versed c++ to translate it.